# Regarding issue of Thread Hung in websphere

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere

I am facing issue of hanging of java thread in our development application. Following are the log trace:

```
020 SystemOut     O --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[8/1/12 11:00:21:136 CDT] 00000023 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 6" (00000027) has been active for 731757 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 2 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
[8/1/12 11:00:24:626 CDT] 00000021 FreePool      E   J2CA0045E: Connection not available while invoking method createOrWaitForConnection for resource jdbc/RTNCTR_DEV.
[8/1/12 11:00:24:636 CDT] 00000021 SystemOut     O 
[8/1/12 11:00:24:636 CDT] 00000021 SystemOut     O --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

unable to find the root cause of this problem , Please advise for possible solutions, folks please as advise as I am stuck up..!!

Comment: I would guess your threads are hanging because websphere cannot get a connection to the database and is stuck. Check on the database how many connections are active as you may be hitting a limit.  When you rebooted both websphere and the db, does the problem reoccur.  Does the connection ever work?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you want to find where that particular thread is stuck by requesting a [javacore thread dump](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/).

On a UNIX platform, you just issue a kill -3 on the process ID. On Windows, you'll need to use [wsadmin commands](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384926) (which also works on UNIX but isn't as quick as the kill -3).

Search the resulting file for `WebContainer : 6`, and that thread's stack trace will show you where in the application or WebSphere the thread is stuck.

See [Problem determination for javacore files from WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21181068).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is stuck waiting for a connection to the datasource 'jdbc/RTNCTR_DEV'. My guess would that either you don't have connections available or you're application is leaking them. Do what beny23 said earlier and that is check if the connections ever works (after a restart perhaps), if it does work and suddenly they stop (say after 10 queries) then you have a leak. If they don't work at all look at the datasource configuration in WAS.

If its a leak then go through your application and find where you're not returning the connection to the pool or closing the connection - all depends on how your application works.

We had a problem similar problems as well. Turned out to be resolved by adding a custom setting on the datasource to set connection settings to false. We of course determined first it wasn't our application that was leaking connections.

Comment: Can you elaborate your statement "adding a custom setting on the datasource to set connection settings to false" further? Thanks.